# Smartface Global.smartface.js is becoming empty

Tags: android, ios, smartface.io

I am new to smartface mobile app development. 
The issue is my Global.Smartface.js is becoming empty once i closed and re-opened the file.

Info: i registered with community license which is free.

Could any one help on this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your question is not clear. Can you post code samples and more information about what you did already to debug the problem ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Below are the steps i did.
1. Open Global.smartface.js in smartface script editor by clicking on "Open File" icon.
2. Added some variables which i feel common for entire app
3. Saved the file and closed it
4. Saved my project and re-opened the Global.smartface.js as same as mentioned in #1
5. I seen the file(Global.smartface.js) is empty.

This is happening all the time for me. What might be the issue?

INFO: I registered with community license.

Thanks

Comment: I think your version has a problem. Try to delete the object folder(it is placed inside data folder of your project), and then save, close, reopen your project.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried with you suggestion. but, still having the same issue. Deleted the object folder, saved the project and re-started machine even and reopened the project. Still Global.smartface.js is becoming empty when i am saving the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solutions. Issue is changing or Modifying Global.Smartface.js file explicitly. We should select "Global" from "Script" dropdown in Script Editor.

Finally i got the solutions.. Thanks for the replies..